# SQL: Identify unique records in server log based on existence of query string parameters

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I am a business end user and have been provided access to a front-end data warehousing tool to query for results stored in a server log. The software in question is Oracle BI Answers which allows for simple and advanced filtering and display of results based on columns requested.

For purposes of this question, assume as a given that the server is receiving requests for http://servername/file.html?param1=xxx&param2=yyy (where xxx and yyy are alphanumeric values).

I need to filter the server log for all requests for file.html where param1=abc and param2=def (i.e., the intersection). The SQL query I am using is below. I'm certain I have it written correctly, but the software appears to be filtering the VISIBLE RESULT itself when I add the AND condition instead of the underlying server requests.

i.e., If I use:

```
("Request Info"."Query Name" LIKE '%param1%' AND "Request Info"."Query Value" LIKE '%abc%') OR ("Request Info"."Query Name" LIKE '%param2%' AND "Request Info"."Query Value" LIKE '%def%')
```

I get results in the form of (counting all the times param1 and param2 appears in the server log):

param1   5
param2   10

But if I use, what I think should be giving me the intersection of the two values above, I get a "No Results Found" error (when I know for a fact that there are results at the intersection):

```
("Request Info"."Query Name" LIKE '%param1%' AND "Request Info"."Query Value" LIKE '%abc%') AND ("Request Info"."Query Name" LIKE '%param2%' AND "Request Info"."Query Value" LIKE '%def%')
```

I get the following error message:

No Results - The specified criteria didn't result in any data. This is often caused by applying filters that are too restrictive or that contain incorrect values. Please check your Request Filters and try again.

Comment: Can you show us the "Query Name" and "Query Value" for one of the intersecting records?

Comment: Note that this is probably not an intersection as you are saying (with your code) that all of these values must match IN THE SAME ROW. I expect that you have a join here that we're not seeing. What you need to do for intersection is split out the second half into a subquery enclosed by an EXISTS test -- or you could put both queries into subqueries and JOIN them to each other then return those results.